# Calculate the difference in days between two dates using JSTL

Tags: jstl

I have set two dates using jstl. One is a current date and other is 7 days from now.

```
 <jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
    <fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${now}" var="nowDate"/>

<jsp:setProperty name="weekDate" property="time" value="${weekDate.time + 604800000}"/>
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${weekDate}" var="weekDate"/>
```

I want to be able to find the difference between two days

I used the code shown below using code below , but

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${(weekDate.time - nowDate.time) / (1000*60*60*24)}" var="dateDifference"/>
 ${dateDifference}
```

I get error saying

> Property 'time' not found on type java.lang.String

How can I find the difference in days for the two dates?

Answer (score 0):

use original objectname.time and parseNumber because we require # of days.

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date" />
<fmt:parseNumber value="${(now.time - weekDate.time) / (1000*60*60*24) }" integerOnly="true" />

Comment: If it's part of your answer, please add the code from the comment into it through an [edit].